# Python: is entry point of execution (__main__)?

Tags: python, class, object

I wrote the following python code and tried to use `__main__` to initialize two class objects, but I got the following errors when running `python classPerson.py`. I wonder what's the correct way of initializing class objects in python.

```
Person(object):
    def __init__(self, name, salary):
        self.name = name
        self.salary = salary


    def getName():
        return self.name

    def getSalary():
        return self.salary

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        bob = Person('Bob Smith', 40000)

        sue = Person('Sue Funk', 35000)

        print 'bob makes a salary of %d' % (bob.getSalary)
        print 'sue's full name is %s' % (sue.getName)
```

**Errors:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "classTest1.py", line 1, in <module>
    class Person(object):
  File "classTest1.py", line 14, in Person
    bob = Person('Bob Smith', 40000)
NameError: name 'Person' is not defined
```

Comment: Your code is invalid, as posted, because the last string literal won't compile (single quotes around a value with an un-escaped single quote in it).

Answer (score 4):

You need to *unindent* the `if __name__` block to *not* be part of the `Person` class.

It is being executed too early and the `Person` class is still being built at that time.

By indenting it to the same level as the methods in the `Person` class body, you made the test part of the class definition. It is being executed as when the class is being defined still, so the `Person` class reference does not yet exist.

Corrected code:

```
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, name, salary):
        self.name = name
        self.salary = salary

    def getName(self):
        return self.name

    def getSalary(self):
        return self.salary

if __name__ == '__main__':
    bob = Person('Bob Smith', 40000)

    sue = Person('Sue Funk', 35000)

    print 'bob makes a salary of %d' % (bob.getSalary())
    print "sue's full name is %s" % (sue.getName())
```

Note:

1. you also need to *call* the `getSalary()` and `getName()` methods.
2. Give all methods a `self` parameter.
3. use correct quoting for your strings (`sue's` contains a single quote, best to use double quotes for delimiting that string).

Comment: And according to [PEP-8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) the methods should be named `get_name` and `get_salary`.

Comment: @Matthias: I'm not fussy about naming conventions for newbies. That all can come later.

Comment: That's why I added it as a comment and didn't try to write an own answer.

Answer (score 4):

you can't use the Person class while it is defined you have to put it one indentation level down

```
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, name, salary):
        self.name = name
        self.salary = salary


    def getName(self):
        return self.name

    def getSalary(self):
        return self.salary

if __name__ == '__main__':
    bob = Person('Bob Smith', 40000)

    sue = Person('Sue Funk', 35000)

    print 'bob makes a salary of %d' % (bob.getSalary())
    print "sue's full name is %s" % (sue.getName())
```

**EDIT** corrected last statement according Sukrit Kalra comment

**EDIT** the correct way to call a method is using parenthesis and the correct way to define it is using self in parameters **but** the idiomatic way to use the class is to not use getters and setters so

```
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, name, salary):
        self.name = name
        self.salary = salary


if __name__ == '__main__':
    bob = Person('Bob Smith', 40000)

    sue = Person('Sue Funk', 35000)

    print 'bob makes a salary of %d' % (bob.salary)
    print "sue's full name is %s" % (sue.name)
```

[python is not java!](http://dirtsimple.org/2004/12/python-is-not-java.html)

Comment: Check the last `print` statement. :)

Comment: There are more problems still; you need to pay attention to how those methods are going to work (hint: calling them would be a start, and giving the methods the correct parameters would also help).

Comment: corrected it, did not care how few not idiomatic python code it was

Answer (score 2):

You have indented the `if __name__ == "__main__"` block one level too far. Try running

```
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, name, salary):
        self.name = name
        self.salary = salary


    def getName(self):
        return self.name

    def getSalary(self):
        return self.salary

if __name__ == '__main__':
    bob = Person('Bob Smith', 40000)
    sue = Person('Sue Funk', 35000)
    print 'bob makes a salary of %d' % (bob.getSalary())
    print "sue's full name is %s" % (sue.getName())
```

Since, in your code, the `if` block is in the `Person` class and you are making objects of that class before the class is built, it is giving you an error.

Comment: wow, you guys are fast! Thank you very much! You guys reminded me the importance of indentation in python! :) appreciate it.

Comment: There are several more problems with the code still; see my answer for addressing one more problem Sukrit has not yet addressed. :-)

Comment: Can't believe I missed that Martijn! Will fix it in the code right away. Thanks. :)